# Python cached code from current commit

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

I am trying to run a python file with and without my changes (which involves changing a few data structures) to verify that the output before and after the change remains same. To do this, I followed answers on [Execute code on the previous commit without hard resetting the latest commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700293/execute-code-on-the-previous-commit-without-hard-resetting-the-latest-commit) which basically involves checking out to a previous commit and running the unmodified code. But, python somehow retains the module in cache. I have verified that the code changes but the current version is cached. Hence, it runs same code twice.

Comment: Are there any `.pyc` files and/or a __pycache__ folder?

Comment: Yes, there was. Thanks, removed it. Works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Find and delete any `.pyc` files and the `__pycache__` folder in your project to make sure that changes to the source also affect imported modules